# Use Tab Key to switch between files / text windows

Tags: 14.04

I'm a new Ubuntu user (14.04) and I'm wondering if the Tab key can be used like it is in Windows to move between files or text windows. For example, I have a long list of files I'd like to rename; with windows one can double click (or right-click > Rename), type the new file name, then hit Tab and move down the list to the next file without having to double click again. Or, if I have a large webpage with information boxes to fill out (e.g. address form when ordering online) one can fill out a box then hit Tab to move to the next one without moving the mouse and clicking.

Is there a way to do this with Ubuntu? It's not a big thing, but it can be a pain in the ass to click each file or box individually.

Thank you!

Comment: Moved my comment to the answers section so that you can accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to boxes while you are in a webpage. I do not think tab will help you in navigating files. For this I suggest  <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename the file, type your desired file name and hit   <kbd>▼</kbd>   twice to save and highlight the next file.